# What type of variable would be best for array?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently declaring `multiple arrays`, more than 25, that contain numbers and spaces, as type `Variant`. I understand that Variant can slow down a macro a lot. **The question**: is `Variant` the correct choice, or would a different type be better? Sample code is below...

```
Dim RM1() As Variant
RM1() = Array("64", "65", " ", "66", "67", " ", "68", "69", " ", _
        "70", "71", " ", "72", "73", " ", "74", "75", " ", "76", _
        " ", "77", "", "78", " ", "79", " ")

Dim RM2() As Variant
RM2() = Array("20", " ", " ", "21")
```

etc. etc.

Comment: I'm curious where you heard Variants will cause issues? It may or may not be true but still would not make a noticeable difference overall,  unless you're using huge arrays or complex calculations.  I think most people just stick with array.  Most programming taks have numerous ways they can be accomplished, but sometimes "the best choice" isn't the most efficient - as opposed to the most "accepted"... especially if you're learning from forums, etc

Comment: *(but an interesting question nonetheless+)*

Comment: @ashleedawg Thank you for the comment +1; to answer your ?, on SO.  I'm using a lot of arrays, and i was trying to bypass a lot of testing of each variable type to see which variable type would be better, and hoping one of you vba-demigods could help me understand a little better.

Comment: The question is indeed interesting so +1, but to be realistic Unless your array consists of thousands of elements and your macro has logarithmic complexity, it really doesn't matter what type you use, you are working on a computer that can process billions of operations per second, not on a tetris device.

Comment: It makes a bigger difference *how* you're going to be using them. For example, Ranges and Arrays go very efficiently together.

Comment: You *have* to use `Variant` if you want to populate them using the `Array` function.

Comment: Without context of _how_ the array is to be used this Q is meaningless.

Comment: @Rory +1, Thank you, this is what i thought, I was asking for a more informed opinion, and you provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable's [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary) must be [`Variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/variant-data-type) in order to be used with the [`Array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/array-function) function.

---

> ### Array Function
>
> **Syntax: `Array (`** *`arglist`* `)`
>
> **Returns a `Variant` containing an array.**
>
> The required *`arglist`* argument is a comma-delimited list of values that are assigned to the elements of the array contained within the ***Variant***.
>
> <sub>***NOTE:*** a **Variant** that is not declared as an array can still contain an array. A **Variant** variable can contain an array of any type, *except fixed-length strings and user-defined types.* Although a **Variant** containing an array is conceptually different from an array whose elements are of type **Variant**, the array elements are accessed in the same way.</sub>
>
> <sup>([**Source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/array-function))</sup>

---

### Is *processing speed* affected by array's data type?

I tested your theory that the *speed of operations* is affected by an array's *data type*.

With your example, there is only one data type besides `Variant` that could be used (`String`) since your array is hold numbers as well as "spaces".

---

## ***Result Summary:***

**Numeric** (5 million loops)<sup>***†***</sup>**

```
Integer()   1.08 sec   20% faster than Variant             
Long()      1.09 sec                                       
Single()    1.29 sec                                       
Variant()   1.34 sec                                       
Double()    1.37 sec
```

**Numeric** (25 million loops)<sup>***†***</sup>**

```
Variant()   6.16 sec   Variant is 9% faster than String    
String()    6.76 sec
```

**Numbers stored as Text** (5 million loops)<sup>***†***</sup>**

```
Integer()   5.45 sec   Variant is 32% faster than Integer  
Variant()   7.99 sec
```

> **Therefore**, it it true: Arrays of non-Variant data types are handled up to **20% faster** than an Array of Variants. However in this case, that means `0.6 seconds` were saved on **2 billion** interactions with the arrays.
>
> ---
>
> ### Using GMalc's [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50663801/8112776):
>
> Important to note: in the case of the OP's example data:  **Storing numbers as Strings (like your sample data) your real problem,** taking up to **six times longer** than using a numeric data type.

---

## Detailed Test Results & Code:

Run-times<sup>***†***</sup> using Strings of four numeric digits:

```
    Type       #1     #2     #3     #4     #5   
 ----------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ 
  Variant()   6.18   6.15   6.15   6.14   6.12 seconds
  Variant()    6.2    6.2   6.21   6.18   6.19  
  Variant()   6.22   6.18   6.16   6.19   6.19  
  Variant()   6.14   6.11   6.12   6.11   6.14  
  String()    7.09   6.79   7.12   6.73   6.77  
  String()    6.87   6.72   6.77    6.7   6.68  
  String()     6.7   6.69    6.7   6.69    6.7  
  String()     6.7   6.68   6.68   6.71   6.69
```

Run-times<sup>***†***</sup> using 4-digit numbers:

```
  Integer()   1.09   1.07   1.08   1.08   1.09 seconds
  Integer()   1.07   1.09   1.08   1.07   1.08  
  Integer()   1.08   1.07   1.08   1.08   1.09  
  Integer()   1.09   1.08   1.07   1.08   1.09  
  Long()      1.08   1.08   1.09   1.08   1.08  
  Long()      1.09   1.08   1.08   1.09   1.08  
  Long()      1.09   1.08    1.2   1.09   1.08  
  Long()      1.09   1.09   1.09   1.09   1.09  
  Single()    1.29    1.3   1.29   1.29   1.29  
  Single()    1.29   1.29   1.29   1.28   1.28  
  Single()    1.29   1.28   1.29   1.29   1.28  
  Single()    1.29   1.27    1.3   1.29   1.29  
  Double()    1.28   1.27   1.29    1.3   1.34  
  Double()    1.34   1.34   1.52   1.76   1.43  
  Double()     1.3   1.33    1.4    1.3   1.35  
  Double()    1.38   1.41   1.38    1.4   1.33  
  Variant()   1.33   1.34   1.32   1.34   1.32  
  Variant()   1.32   1.34   1.32   1.33   1.32  
  Variant()   1.34   1.34   1.34   1.42   1.31  
  Variant()   1.35   1.39   1.33   1.38   1.38
```

Run-times<sup>***†***</sup> for Variant/Integer, 4-digit numbers:

```
  Variant()   6.61   6.59   6.59   6.59    6.6 seconds
  Variant()   8.36   8.88   8.29   8.17   8.18  
  Variant()   9.13   9.41   8.59   8.25   8.27  
  Variant()   8.25   8.17   8.16   8.38   8.29  
  Integer()   5.45   5.45   5.43   5.44   5.45  
  Integer()   5.45   5.44   5.44   5.45   5.45  
  Integer()   5.44   5.44   5.45   5.45   5.45  
  Integer()   5.44   5.45   5.46   5.45   5.45
```

<sup>***†***</sup>**Testing method:**

- <sub>5 million loops per #test, each "interacting" an array 4 times, multiplied by 5x4 processes

  = **400 Million** "interactions" with array on each data type</sub>
- <sub>25 million loops per #test, each "interacting" an array 4 times, multiplied by 5x4 processes

  = **2 Billion** "interactions" with array</sub>

---

### Testing Code:

Below is the code I slapped together for the test:

```
Option Explicit
Const loops = 25000000
Public arr1(1 To loops) As Integer, arr2(1 To loops) As Integer, el

Sub runTests()
    Dim t As Long
    Debug.Print TypeName(arr1) & " (" & loops & " loops): ";
    For t = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print "#" & t & ": " & Format(testArray, "0.00") & "sec, ";
        DoEvents
    Next t
    Debug.Print "Done."
End Sub

Function testArray() As Double
'are arrays faster to use when data type is non-variant?
'I consider this procedure to be "touching" the arrays a "total of (4 * [Loops]) times"
    Dim x As Long, startTime As Single: startTime = Timer
    For x = 1 To loops 'populate arr1 with 4-digit numeric strings
        arr1(x) = IIf(TypeName(arr2) = "String", CStr(Int((Rnd() * 11000) + 1001)), Int((Rnd() * 11000) + 1001))
    Next x

    For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1) 'copy arr1 to arr2, one element at a time
        arr2(x) = arr1(x)
    Next x

    For Each el In arr2 'iterate & clear arr2
        If el = IIf(TypeName(arr2) = "String", "99999", 99999) Then '(won't be found)
            Debug.Print "Found!"
            Exit For
        End If
        el = Null
    Next el
    testArray = (Timer - startTime)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information and test data.